# Bad: stream : FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),

Tags: flutter, dart, stream

I work on a flutter app and I am creating the page to auth the user, but when I want to use the function "stream" its poster to me : "The argument type 'Stream<User?>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Stream?'."
here is my code :

```
Widget _handleAuth() {
  return new StreamBuilder<User>(
    stream : FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
      if(snapshot.hasData){
        //we are auth
      } else {
        //we aren't auth
      }
    }
);
```

}

thank you in advance for your answers

Comment: remove user then its will work fine

Comment: thanks you for your answer, now it's work fine